# How to mix multicolumns?

Tags: tables

I want to create a table, that is composed of 4 columns, but at the top I want to have just one whole row with a text, then underneath it two columns, then under each of two columns, another two columns. I have the code below, but I have an error near `After title - Before title`. Any ideas how to fix it?

```
\begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}||p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|  }
 \hline
 \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Main title} \\
 \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{After title }{Before title} \\
 \hline
 Before & After & Before & After \\
 \hline
 column1 & column2 & column3 & column4\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `|` aren't very nice, but I kept them here in the first version, for the 2nd version I applied `booktabs` lines.

`\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{After title }{Before title}` is wrong of course,
as it would use only 2 columns for the first multicolumn and tries to print `{Before title}` -- this is possible, but it's not what is desired.

The second title has to be put into another `\multicolumn`, separated with a `&`!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{p{3cm}|}}      
 \hline
 \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Main title} \\
 \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{After title } & \multicolumn{2}{ c|}{Before title} \\
 \hline
 Before & After & Before & After \\
 \hline
 column1 & column2 & column3 & column4\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\begin{center}



\begin{tabular}{*{4}{p{3cm}}}      
  \toprule
 \multicolumn{4}{c}{Main title} \\
 \midrule
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{After title } & \multicolumn{2}{ c}{Before title} \\
 \midrule
 Before & After & Before & After \\
 \midrule
 column1 & column2 & column3 & column4\\
 \toprule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I recommend starting and ending the table definition with `@{}` to get rid og the excessive space in the start of column 1 and end of column 4.